# Disallow top level of directory, but not subdirectories in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I have a directory that I don't want Google to index at the top level. I currently do the following:

`Disallow: /profiles/`

This stops Google from indexing `https://example.com/profiles/`, but it also stops it from indexing `https://example.com/profiles/exampleuser`. Because new profiles are created every day, it is not feasible to simply add an `allow` statement for every individual subdirectory of `/profiles/`

How can I disallow the profiles directory itself while also allowing any subdirectory of the profiles directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: If you are trying to prevent Google from *indexing* a page, you should not be using `robots.txt` at all. In that case, see Stephen's answer.

I will leave my original answer below, which shows how to set up your `robots.txt` file in the way you're asking for. This will prevent *crawling* of your desired URL pattern, not necessarily indexing.

---

You could use the `$` operator, which matches URLs that end in a specific string:

```
Disallow: /profiles/$
```

You might also consider blocking versions of the page that come with parameters:

```
Disallow: /profiles/?
```

Consider using Google's `robots.txt` testing tool to test your setup, available here:
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-testing-tool

Answer (score 1):

Robots.txt does not prevent indexing, it only prevents crawling. Google may decide to index a URL that is blocked in robots.txt when there are enough links to it, especially external links.

Robots.txt is the right tool when there are too many URLs to crawl.  It is not the right tool for when you want to prevent a single URL from getting indexed.

I would suggest using a `<meta name=robots content=noindex>` tag in the `<head>` of `https://example.com/profiles/` without blocking the page from getting crawled. That way Googlebot will be able to crawl the page and see that it shouldn't be indexed.